# Remove CGroup from systemctl status output

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, services, systemd

I have PHP7.0-FPM running with 125 start servers, and I like to check its status after restarting it. With `systemctl status`, this of course produces over 130 lines of output, making it difficult to read quickly.

```
root@web2:/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d# systemctl --no-pager --full status php7.0-fpm
● php7.0-fpm.service - The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-10-27 13:38:29 CDT; 13min ago
  Process: 5961 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/php/php7.0-fpm-checkconf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5971 (php-fpm7.0)
   Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 125, Requests: 12, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/sec"
    Tasks: 126
   Memory: 294.2M
      CPU: 728ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/php7.0-fpm.service
           ├─5971 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
           ├─5974 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5975 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5976 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5977 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5978 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5979 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5980 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5981 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5982 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5983 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5984 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5985 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5986 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5987 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5988 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5989 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5990 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5991 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5992 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5993 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5994 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5995 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5996 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5997 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5998 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5999 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6000 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6001 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6002 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6003 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6004 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6005 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6006 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6007 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6008 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6009 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6010 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6011 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6012 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6013 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6014 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6015 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6016 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6017 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6018 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6019 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6020 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6021 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6022 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6023 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6024 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6025 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6026 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6027 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6028 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6029 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6030 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6031 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6032 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6033 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6034 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6035 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6036 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6037 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6038 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6039 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6040 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6041 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6042 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6043 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6044 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6045 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6046 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6047 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6048 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6049 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6050 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6051 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6052 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6053 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6054 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6055 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6056 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6057 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6058 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6059 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6060 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6061 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6062 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6063 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6064 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6065 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6066 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6067 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6068 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6069 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6070 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6071 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6072 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6073 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6074 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6075 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6076 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6077 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6078 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6079 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6080 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6081 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6082 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6083 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6084 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6085 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6086 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6087 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6088 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6089 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6090 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6091 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6092 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6093 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6094 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6095 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6096 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─6097 php-fpm: pool www
           └─6098 php-fpm: pool www

Oct 27 13:38:29 web2 systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager...
Oct 27 13:38:29 web2 systemd[1]: Started The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

I really don't need all the `CGroup` info that it outputs. I just want the quick status and the few log lines at the bottom. I can filter the output like this:

```
root@web2:/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d# systemctl --no-pager status php7.0-fpm | grep -v "php-fpm: pool www"
● php7.0-fpm.service - The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-10-27 13:38:29 CDT; 19min ago
  Process: 5961 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/php/php7.0-fpm-checkconf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5971 (php-fpm7.0)
   Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 125, Requests: 16, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/sec"
    Tasks: 126
   Memory: 295.5M
      CPU: 737ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/php7.0-fpm.service
           ├─5971 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)                      

Oct 27 13:38:29 web2 systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager...
Oct 27 13:38:29 web2 systemd[1]: Started The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

But then I lose the colored formatting in bash that is also really useful for a quick status check.

Is there any way in `systemctl` or similar command to get this status info without the `CGroup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will be possible to get the color if you process the output in any way. `systemctl` detects when its output isn't a tty and doesn't produce colored output. This is often the default behavior since that's usually what you want.

As a workaround, here's a little script that parses out the CGroup info, and adds the color back on:

```
perl -MTerm::ANSIColor -ne 'next if /^CGroup/ || /├─/; 
    s/(?>: )active/color("bold green").$&.color("reset")/e; print'
```

Pass your `systemctl` output through that and the word `active` will be green:

```
systemctl --no-pager status php7.0-fpm | 
   perl -MTerm::ANSIColor -ne 'next if /^CGroup/ || /├─/; 
    s/(?>: )active/color("bold green").$&.color("reset")/e; print'
```

If you edit your question and add different output (I don't have the service installed so I don't know what else should be colored), I can extend this to other possible outputs.

Comment: I tried your Perl command. It adds the color back alright, but it doesn't filter out the CGroup lines. All the same lines are output.

Comment: @Andrew sorry, I had a bug. Try the updated answer.

Comment: That did it. I modified your code a little bit for the "active" match.

`sudo systemctl --no-pager --full status php7.0-fpm |        perl -MTerm::ANSIColor -ne 'next if /^CGroup/ || /├─/;        s/active \(running\)/color("bold green").$&.color("reset")/e; print'`

And this won't give me the red color on error, but this works well enough. I'll just know if I don't see green immediately, something's not exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

Use [script](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html).

e.g. `script --running -c 'systemctl --no-pager status php7.0-fpm' | grep -v "php-fpm: pool www"`

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdout-is-a-terminal-not-a-pipe